# Virtual environments in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I came across an issue while working with virtual environments in python.

I created a virtual environment named 'venv' and started working on an ipynb in the same. The issue is that when I finished my work and saved it I noticed that the ipynb wasn't saved in .\venv. Shouldn't the ipynb file (I created inside the virtual environment) be saved INSIDE the virtual environment and not in the directory above it with all other notebooks that weren't created inside that virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. In the virtualenv you'll have any package you install in it (for example with pip) but the files you create remain on the path where you work. If you want your virtualenv to use a local package you can install it via `pip install -e`.

It's just en enviroment. That's why it has its own `./bin/` folder

Check:
https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/ an 
https://xkcd.com/1987/